# Android: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.1.1

Tags: android

Error : Sync failed. Unresolved Android dependencies. Failed to resolve:  com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.1.1

Config:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.ercess.ercess_app1"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }



    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.1.1'
        implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    }
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Replace

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.1.1
```

with

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
```

Currently, the most recent available release for appCompat is 28.0.0-rc01, you are trying to pull an unavailable version of appcompat library.

Comment: `rc01` is a release candidate ...and not the latest stable version.

Answer (score 6):

**Root cause:** The version 28.1.1 is not exist.

**Solution:** Use the latest stable version

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

or use latest unstable version

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
```

Answer (score 5):

Many answers already on this one but I feel like noone explaines how to keep it up to date, just how to fix this specific version. So here it is

- The `com.android.support:appcompat` version must match the `compileSdkVersion`
- It is preferable to use stable versions if you release to production
- Look on the [android website](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions) to find the lastest stable version that correspond to your compile version (even is this link gets broken, the info will be available somewhere on the official website)

Example, as of today (end of january 2019), the lastest stable support library version is 28.0.0 (according to android website), so the correct implementation is

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

Comment: Thank you! Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

you'd have to use `api "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1"` -

or the later (future) `api "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2"`
 from [androidx](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/).

using "release candidates" and "alpha versions" is discouraged, because these are not well tested.

just see the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages) ...it recommends `27.1.1`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by trial and error and using some of the answers above.

I changed the appcompat to a lower version "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0"
along with changing

```
compileSdkVersion 27
```

and
    targetSdkVersion 27

I'm still getting warnings but Picasso should now run.

Answer (score 1):

You need also add: implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0' in your gradle file like this:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

and this is a full implementation:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add these below dependencies to solve the issue, try it:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

also change the version of AppCompat as:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

AppCompat Sometimes doesn't work alone. Adding these might solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.1.1'
```

with

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
```